# Numerical Solutions to Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to show that a linear multistep function has a unique solution.

My current idea is to use Banach fixed point theorem. I am not sure how to use it though, any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you formulate again? A numerical algorithm just is. It produces a result which by construction exists and is unique. The only question that remains is how good an approximation to the original problem it is.